# Como fazer uma classe ou função de testes com pytest?

Tags: python

Seja um programa em Python, como, por exemplo, o cálculo de fibonnaci:

```
def fibR(n):
 if n==1 or n==2:
  return 1
 return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
print (fibR(5))
```

Como fazer uma classe/função de testes usando pytest, por exemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fibR(n):
 if n==1 or n==2:
  return 1
 return fibR(n-1)+fibR(n-2)
```

No mesmo diretório:test_fib.py:

```
import pytest
from fib import fibR

def test_fib_1_equals_1():
    assert fibR(1) == 1

def test_fib_2_equals_1():
    assert fibR(2) == 1

def test_fib_6_equals_8():
    assert fibR(6) == 8
```

Resposta de @Tagc da versão em inglês do stackoverflow.

Comment: Legal a sua iniciativa de perguntar e responder. Eu também faço isso. Só penso que você deveria adicionar o link da resposta e explicar, por exemplo, que  as funções devem começar com um prefixo "test_". Acho importante a resposta não ter apenas código. Até mais!

Comment: @Wallace Maxters, obrigado!